# How to wire up deleteOne functionality in a React/Redux & MongoDB App

Tags: mongodb, express, reactjs, redux

I have a React/Redux app that lists transactions, with data stored in a MongoDB collection. 
I have CRUD operations set up and can add and edit transactions, but I am struggling a bit with the delete functionality.

I have a delete endpoint created in Express.js:

```
app.delete('/api/transactions/:id', function(req, res) {
    Transaction.remove({
        _id: req.params.id
    }, function(err, transaction) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json({ message: 'Transaction deleted!' })
    });
});
```

In my Redux action creators I have the following:

```
export function deleteTransaction(id) {
    const request = axios.delete(`/api/transactions/${id}`);

    return {
        type: DELETE_TRANSACTION,
        payload: request
    }
}
```

I am fetching transactions through Redux in the `componentWillMount()` lifecycle method, and then mapping over the results to return a chunk of JSXL

```
{this.props.transactions.map(
    (transaction, i) => 
        <Transaction {...this.props} key={i} transaction={transaction} />
)}
```

I thought I could just create a method like the following:

```
handleDelete(id) {
    this.props.deleteTransaction(id)
        .then(() => {
            this.context.router.push('/');
        });
}
```

Then call this method onClick, and pass in the MongoDB Document `_id` from props, but in hooking this up and tinkering, I was getting errors stating `cannot call deleteTransaction of undefined` then other times it was deleting all collections... all sorts of weird errors that was messing up other areas of the application, so I have reverted and come seeking help from you React/Redux wizards :)

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

### Update

I was calling `handleDelete()` and passing the ID from Transaction.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import numeral from 'numeral';
import moment from 'moment';

import TransactionEdit from './TransactionEdit';

export default class Transaction extends Component {

    render() {

        const { transaction } = this.props;

        return (
            <tr>
                <td>{transaction.name}</td>
                <td>{moment(transaction.date).format('Do MMM YYYY')}</td>
                <td>{`£${numeral(transaction.amount).format('£ 0,0[.]00')}`}</td>
                <td><Link to={`/transaction/edit/${transaction._id}`} className="button">Edit</Link></td>
                <td><button onClick={this.props.handleDelete(transaction._id)}className="button">Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
        );      
    }
}
```

For clarity, this is the entire Transactions.js file:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import * as actionCreators from '../actions/actionCreators';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

import Transaction from './Transaction';

class Transactions extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.fetchTransactions();
    }

    handleDelete(id) {
        this.props.deleteTransaction(id)
            .then(() => {
                this.context.router.push('/');
            });
    }

    static contextTypes = {
        router: PropTypes.object
    }

    render() {

        const { transactions } = this.props;

        if (!transactions) {
            return (
                    <div>
                        <p>Loading...</p>
                    </div>
            )
        }


        return (
            <section>
                <h2>Transactions <Link className="actionlink" to="/transactions/add">Add</Link></h2>
                <table className="financials -transactions">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th className="activefilter">Amount</th>
                            <th className="actions">&nbsp;</th>
                            <th className="actions">&nbsp;</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {this.props.transactions.map(
                        (transaction, i) => 
                            <Transaction {...this.props} key={i} transaction={transaction} />
                    )}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </section>
         );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { 
        transactions: state.transactions.all 
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Transactions);
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id is undefined in your `handleDelete` helper function because I believe you need to bind `this` instance of the `handleDelete` function in order to pass the id. In your `onClick` method try `onClick={this.props.handleDelete.bind(this, transaction._id)}`

Comment: Hello Eric - I have edited my original post. Thank you :)

Comment: It's the same question, Håken.

Comment: Thanks Eric, will try this when I get hone this evening :)